# Can I pass an attribute from an HTML element to the JQuery .delay() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to delay the appearance of text on a page (actually in a Twine - https://twinery.org/) by an amount defined in the attributes of the span object like so:

```js
$(".fadeIn").each(function() {
  alert(parseInt($(this).attr("fadeInAfter")))
});

$(".fadeIn").delay(parseInt($(this).attr("fadeInAfter"))).fadeIn(1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="hide fadeIn" fadeInAfter="1000">This should fade in after 1 second</span>

<span class="hide fadeIn" fadeInAfter="5000">This should fade in after 5 seconds</span>
```

With this code the alert boxes fire with the correct values, but the spans fade in immediately.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Am I going about it the wrong way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very important difference between your code where `alert()` is called and the code where you set up the delay: the `.each()` method invokes your callback function for **each** `<span>` individually. That's why getting the attribute value works. In your `.delay()` call, the code is evaluated with `this` set to whatever it is in the calling context.

It's easy to fix: do your `.delay()` calls in a `.each()` callback too:

```
$(".fadeIn").each(function() {
  $(this).delay(parseInt($(this).attr("fadeInAfter"))).fadeIn(1000);
});
```